# How to use the same Bind for two comboboxes? Conflict between comboboxes

Tags: python, tkinter, data-binding

I would like to click on the combobox "Nation" and activate 2 comboboxes: combobox "City" and combobox "Monumenti". The two comboboxes "City" and "Monuments" conflict with each other because they are combined by the same Bing Nation (main combobox). Basically if you activate "City" then you don't activate "Monuments" and vice versa. I need to click on "Nation" to activate the two comboboxes at the same time.

PROBLEM: If I click on the combobox "Nation", the combobox City is activated correctly, but not the combobox "Monuments".

```
combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)   
combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_monuments)
```

P.S: For my curiosity I tried to delete the combobox "Nation" and I noticed that subsequently the combobox "Monumenti" worked well and was correctly combined with the main combobox "Nation".

How to solve?

```
def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nation FROM All_Nation')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def combo_city(event=None):
    nation = combo_nation.get()
    cursor.execute('ok, sql correct, needless to write it = ?', (nation,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_city['values'] = result
    return result

#Nation
lbl_nation = Label(root, text="nation", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#a8dd71", fg="white")
lbl_nationplace(x=6, y=60)
combo_nation = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")
combo_nation.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_nation.set("Select nation")
combo_nation['values'] = combo_nation()
combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)    


#city
lbl_city = Label(root, text="city", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="white", fg="black")
lbl_city.place(x=6, y=110)

combo_city = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")
combo_city.place(x=180, y=110)
combo_city.set("Select city")


#MONUMENTS
lbl_monuments = Label(root, text="monuments", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#a8dd71", fg="white")
lbl_monuments.place(x=600, y=60)
combo_monuments = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")

combo_monuments.place(x=680, y=60)
combo_monuments.set("Select monuments")



def combo_monuments(event=None):
  
    cursor.execute('ok, sql correct, needless to write it')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_monuments['value'] = result
    combo_monuments.current(0)
    return result

combo_monuments['values'] = combo_nation()
combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_monuments)
```

Comment: Why don't you combine `combo_city()` and `combo_monuments()` into one function, for example `on_nation_changed()` and then `combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_nation_changed)`.

Comment: @acw1668 I am new to Python. Could you show me how you say with my answer code please? I do not understand. Thanks

Comment: Another way is change `combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_monuments)` to `combo_nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_monuments, add=True)`, then both `combo_city()` and `combo_monuments()` will be executed if a nation is selected.

Comment: @acw1668 Perfect. It works fine, thanks! One question: the question: in this case, "add = True", can it limit some function of the combobox elements? Ie the elements of the combobox, with "add = True", can I use them normally for any purpose? IF YOU WRITE ME YOUR KIND SUGGESTION AS A QUESTION, I WILL ASSIGN THE QUESTION THE ANSWER. Thanks